# How do I list records in a table only if a field is not present in another table?

Tags: mysql

First time posting here so please excuse my manners or lack thereof.

My issue is related to a single MySQL database.

How do I use a query to list all records where a specific field is not found in another table's specific field?  So far I can use `left outer join` to show matches but I want to show misses.

```
select * from TABLE_A    
left outer join TABLE_B
on (TABLE_B.id = TABLE_A.field)
where TABLE_B.id is not null;
```

How do I syntax a query to show records that do not have a match in TABLE_B.field? Leveraging "is null" provides no results.

Comment: Hello.  I used 'is not null' in the query to validate it was working.  That said I am trying to show misses.  I need to result in a list of records from TABLE_A where a field is not found in TABLE_B.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You asked this question well. Please keep participating!

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field from TABLE_B ) 
This shows all the fields from table A that doesn´t have the field listed in table B.

Comment: Thanks @BK435 I think I was looking at this the wrong way, your comment helped me solve.

Answer (score 0):

A left join with where Table_B.id is null should work.

If you are not getting any results, it could be that there is no `where the table_B = Table_A.field` do not match.

I would suggest looking at your expect data output again more carefully.